# How to know if the email has already been registered in firebase authentication, javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am doing an email update for the user, but first I need to know if the email has been previously registered in firebase authentication.

In this way I updated the email:

```
 if(administrador.correo != vm.editedItem.correo){
       console.log("ESTA ACTUALIZANDO CORREO");
       console.log(vm.editedItem);
       firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(vm.editedItem.correo, vm.editedItem.contrasenia)
                                    .then(function(userCredential) {
                                        console.log("USER CREDENTIAL");
                                        console.log(userCredential);
                                        userCredential.user.updateEmail(vm.editedItem.correo)
                                        .then(function() {
                                            console.log("email update");
                                        // Update successful.
                                        }).catch(function(error) {
                                            console.log("ERROR");
                                            console.log(error);
                                        // An error happened.
                                        });
                                    })
                              }
```

But before I can update the email I have to validate if it already exists, if the email exists, since it is not allowed to update mail and if the email does not exist, therefore I update the email.

Beforehand thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code. I think you are trying to change same email using which you are logged in. I made some minor changes and comments.

```
if (administrador.correo != vm.editedItem.correo) {
    console.log("ESTA ACTUALIZANDO CORREO");
    console.log(vm.editedItem);
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(vm.currentItem.correo, vm.editedItem.contrasenia)  // sign in with current email and password
        .then(function (userCredential) {
            console.log("USER CREDENTIAL");
            console.log(userCredential);
            userCredential.user.updateEmail(vm.editedItem.correo)  // update new email
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("email update");
                    // Update successful.
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("ERROR");
                    console.log(error);
                    // An error happened.
                    // if updated user email already exists, it returns error code: auth/email-already-in-use
                });
        })
}
```

follow this link for more [updateEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#updateemail)

Answer (score 0):

If error occurred then check Error Code auth/email-already-in-use.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

Or, Use `admin.auth().getUserByEmail()`. Build to Cloud Functions and call a function from your app.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUserByEmail
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable